# How to use conditional styles in a chart on jasper reports?

Tags: styles, jasper-reports, report, conditional-statements

I want to paint my bars (in a bar chart), according to some conditions, but I can't find a way how to do this...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know since what version it is working like that, but if you have the latest it should work:

- Open the report navigation;
- Click with the right button on the branch "Styles" and click to add a new one;
- On the new style you click again with the right button and create a conditional style;
- Right click again on the new conditional style and edit your condition, after that you just have to setup your style as you want.

Comment: tks, but it doesn't work in a chart!  
I'd like to apply different styles to different bars, according to its values...